# JAVA массив ввод с клавиатуры

Tags: java, массивы, матрицы, ввод

Поняла что в циклах for не так записанный оператор и как результат заполняет один массив одним и тем же числом, в то время как должна проходить итерация каждый раз как вводится новое число с клавиатуры и заполнять новую ячейку, возможно не так объявила массив. Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: 1) читать легче; 2) можно копировать; 3) поиск работает. Исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1358801/edit) ниже текста вопроса.

Comment: Для заполнения/печати двумерного массива нужно использовать _вложенные циклы_ по двум независимым индексам `i, j`.  Показанный код записывает/печатает только элементы, расположенные на главной диагонали квадратного массива.

Comment: разобрались ? или ещё надо помощь?

Comment: ещё надо помощь)